# Nuxt 3 useFetch sometimes returns null

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I want to get some data from HTTP API and display it on the page:

```html
<template>
  <div>
   Kyiv Time: {{ timeData.utc_datetime }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data: timeData } = await useFetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Kiev')
</script>
```

Sometimes page loads correctly, and sometimes I got an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'utc_datetime')` in the template. So await doesn't really wait for the HTTP request.

How can I wait for HTTP request during SSR (and client-side as well)?

My nuxt config is empty, here the project [sources](https://github.com/eugen1j/nuxt3-use-fetch-example)

Comment: The fetch hook is not blocking. Give a search to `fetch vs asyncData`. You can either put conditionals + non blocking or use a blocking approach.

Comment: `await useFetch` should be blocking. `fetch` and `useLazyFetch` are not.

Comment: @some-user oh yeah? I need to update my knowledge there apparently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check not only `data` but also `error`. If an error occurred while fetching (e.g. timeout), `data` will be `null`.

You can either handle this in your template:

```html
<div v-if="data">
...
</div>
<div v-else>
...
</div>
```

or throw an error in script:

```js
if (error.value) {
  throw createError(...)
}
```